# Does PetaPoco support a Sybase database?

Tags: sybase, petapoco

My team is interested in using PetaPoco for one our projects however since the DBMS is Sybase we would want to know if PetaPoco supports it.

If it does, any example of how the connection string would look like will be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, PetaPoco does not support Sybase.

You could find that information in the PetaPoco documentation:

> Works with SQL Server, SQL Server CE, MySQL, PostgreSQL and Oracle.

... or in the source code:

```
enum DBType
{
    SqlServer,
    SqlServerCE,
    MySql,
    PostgreSQL,
    Oracle,
    SQLite
}
```